# 400 error with multipart-form-data request

Tags: java, android, http, multipartform-data

I want to Sync all the local phone contact with my server ,so i am uploading all the contacts with server with json payload so  i am making Multipart-form-data request but the server give 400 error every time

My server code is

```
@POST
@Consumes(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_XML, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON,MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN})
public Response handleUpload(@FormDataParam("filed1") InputStream stream) {

    ByteArrayOutputStream result = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    try {
        while ((length = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
            result.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }

        log.debug("string is "+result.toString("UTF-8")); 
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        log.debug("Exception "+e.getMessage()); 

    }
    // StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name() > JDK 7


    return Response.ok().build();
}
```

My MultiPart req class

```
public class MultiPartReq {
    private static final String tag=MultiPartReq.class.getSimpleName();
    private final String boundary;
    private static final String LINE_FEED = "\r\n";
    private HttpURLConnection httpConn;
    private String charset;
    private OutputStream outputStream;
    private PrintWriter writer;


    public MultiPartReq(String requestURL, String charset)
            throws IOException {
        this.charset = charset;

        // creates a unique boundary based on time stamp
        boundary = "===" + System.currentTimeMillis() + "===";
        URL url = new URL(requestURL);
        httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setUseCaches(false);
        httpConn.setDoOutput(true);    // indicates POST method
        httpConn.setDoInput(true);
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Type",
                "multipart/form-data; boundary=" + boundary);
        outputStream = httpConn.getOutputStream();
        writer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, charset), true);
    }

           public void addFormField(String name, String value) {

        writer.append("--").append(boundary).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"").append(name).append("\"")
                .append(LINE_FEED);

        writer.append(value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.append("--").append(boundary);
        writer.flush();

    }


    public void addHeaderField(String name, String value) {
        writer.append(name + ":" + value).append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.flush();
    }


    public List<String> finish() throws IOException {
        List<String> response = new ArrayList<String>();
        writer.append(LINE_FEED).flush();
        writer.append("--" + boundary + "--").append(LINE_FEED);
        writer.close();

        // checks server's status code first
        int status = httpConn.getResponseCode();
        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    httpConn.getInputStream()));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                response.add(line);
            }
            reader.close();
            httpConn.disconnect();
        } else {
            throw new IOException("Server returned non-OK status: " + status);
        }
        Log.e(tag,""+response.toString());
        return response;
    }
}
```

making a req to my server

```
private  void postToUrl() {


        String url="http://35.200.xx.xx:/example";
        String charset="UTF-8";

        try {

            MultiPartReq multiPartReq=new MultiPartReq(url,charset);
            multiPartReq.addHeaderField("Authorization","E9X422gPUg39wvsM");
            multiPartReq.addHeaderField("Accept","application/json");
            multiPartReq.addFormField("field1","test");
            multiPartReq.finish();

    }
```

Server give 400 error every time..when i try with postman it work fine.What is wrong with my code i can change both server and client code.